# /bin/sh: node: command not found (JavaScript not running)

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to make my first project being a tic tac toe game in VS code.

I finished all of the Javascript, HTML and CSS and whenever I try to run the Javascript I
keep getting "/bin/sh: node: command not found" and none of it working.

I installed Homebrew but it seems it's not not finding the node or somethings
not making a connection somewhere...

I'd appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: If you have HTML and CSS, shouldn't you be running your project *in the browser* and not in Node.js?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=negokaz.live-server-preview VSCode extension

> Preview your HTML file with localhost server live-reloading enabled.